# let and '$:' operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I'm studing sveltekit and I always see the following statement

```
let { session, supabase, profile } = data
$: ({ session, supabase, profile } = data)
```

what it is the meaning of "$:"?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations

Comment: Covered in the docs: [Reactivity](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SvelteKit, the `$:` symbol is used to create a ***reactive statement***.
It's often referred to as a:
"***reactive declaration***" or  "***reactive statement***",
and it is to be re-executed whenever the variables change.

You can read about it here:
https://geoffrich.net/posts/svelte-$-meanings/

or here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_variables_props#